# canvas text distorted in landscape

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have draw following graph using canvas 
[image]

It works fine in portrait but in landscape text get distorted

[image]

I dont want to scale text size.

Comment: you should draw another graph for landscape in the same way.

Comment: @keshav I didnt understand you.

Comment: you can get the state of device so check if it is in landscape ,then adjust the thing of graph accordingly.